# Help figuring out make/model/year of this bike?

Tags: identify-this-bike

I am trying to figure out more info about this bike. It was painted by a precious owner, not the person selling it. I have not seen the bike in person, nor do I know much about bikes, but it looks like it has friction shifters? So based on [this](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/47078/how-can-i-tell-what-year-my-bike-was-made/47116#47116) I guess that means 80's or earlier?

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Stolen BSO of an unascertainable year. The paint and lack of provenance are a sign that it's likely stolen. In terms of frame, it's a BSO and those are undateable as even some 2017 BSOs have one piece cranks and friction shifters. Also, we don't do valuations. It's worth what it's worth to you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I tell what year my bike was made?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/47078/how-can-i-tell-what-year-my-bike-was-made)

Comment: Well, its got suicide levers on it, so I'd think that it'd be early 80s at the latest, probably some time in the 70s. But I agree its a [tag:BSO].

Comment: I'd go 80's for a guess.  There are some beefy tyres there that look much newer style.  Its probably an 80s store brand bike that has had new tyres and either a new saddle or bartape fitted.  Schrader valve wheels, sissy brake levers and clear/white wheel reflectors suggest the American market.  Steel pedals not plastic ones so 90s is less likely.   Steel spoke protector suggests a bit of quality to the build, but ashtabula one-piece cranks suggest not a lot of quality.  The paint job might also be a face lift to sell it.

Answer (score 2):

Given the bottom bracket type, the thin pressed dropouts and the type of seatbinding bolt used, this was not originally a particularly special bike.

It looks like a well-done refurbishment. Look after it, enjoy it, but if it gets bent or stolen, don't worry too much about saving it or restoring it again.