# Raleigh Bike Model Identification

Tags: identify-this-bike

I've been searching through craigslist for a road bike, and I ran across a decent-looking Raleigh Supercourse that's the right size and price ($300). However, neither I nor the current owner have any idea what year/model it is. Could you guys help me identify it?

The specs (that I know of) are:

Shifters: Shimano RX100

Rear Derailleur: Shimano 105

Front Derailleur: Exage 500LX

[image: The Mystery Bike]

Comment: Exage 500 LX was late 80s - early 90s. RX100 was early 90s. I'd look at Raleigh catalogues (you can find these online) from say 88-94, but I'd guess this is a 90-92. Does it have any stickers like Reynolds xyz or something else that might give some clues? It seems like the [original craigslist](https://frederick.craigslist.org/bik/d/raleigh-road-bike/6203483275.html) poster thought this was a Raleigh super course.

Comment: Does the year really matter? If you like it, buy it.

Comment: I'd determine the model year from this answer: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/47078/11160

Comment: I do agree with @RoboKaren - its not a particularly valuable bike or anything, and bikes are not like supermodels (the age doesn't matter that much). If it's in good condition and safe to ride, and you like it, its a decent enough bike to start out on til you find something you like. Just be sure to haggle. You can try BikeForums or something for valuations.

Comment: Horizontal top tubes are the best-looking bikes IMO.  If it fits you then go for it.  I rode a 1980s steel Morrison road bike for a bit and that helped show me just how much faster a road bike is over the MTB I was riding at the time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I tell what year my bike was made?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/47078/how-can-i-tell-what-year-my-bike-was-made)