# Can someone tell me what year this Elgin Sears Roebuck bike is and what model?

Tags: identify-this-bike, vintage

Sears and Roebuck Elgin vintage

[image]

Comment: That's a gorgeous bike.   Chain looks a little bit slack is all, and mind out any batteries in the "tank" don't leak.

Comment: Almost certainly prior to 1970.  But how much before is hard to guess.  Could easily be from the late 1940s.  (But if I had to take a stab I would say 1957.)

Comment: Use this as a guide. My guess is that you'll use the answer that refers to back catalogues and fan websites: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/47078/11160

Comment: Skiptooth cranks and lack of CPSC reflectors are a guide and really should be in the reference question...

Answer (score 2):

It looks a lot like this [1941 Elgin Pilot Deluxe Special](https://luxlow.com/bicycles/1941-elgin-pilot-deluxe-special-bicycle/)

[image]

Bent seat tube, fork support, style of chainguard, fenders, seat, chainring, rear dropouts

[image]

Similar wishbone seat stays, seat post

The originally posted bike is missing the rack and does not have the kickstand - the the rear dropout is a similar shape and looks like it would have supported the pictured kickstand.
The handlebars, grips and trim paint are different - possibly older or newer style than the original post