# Help identifying folding bike

Tags: identify-this-bike

Can anyone identify or provide any info about the make, model, etc. of this folding red bike, with a 20-inch rear smaller front wheel?

[image]

The only markings found on the bike:

[image]

Comment: Are there any logos or branding anywhere on the bike?

Comment: @KeithWM I reposted the item with the only other markings on the bike that I was able to find.  The bike is not in my possession.

Comment: I'm just curious, why do we keep getting this same question all the time?

Comment: @ojs I am just trying to navigate the functionality of the stackexchange platform as a beginner, so there is a little trial and error involved.  My apologies for the repeats.  Just looking for a little help from people with more knowledge than me about bikes.

Comment: Pro tip: "Related" on top right. But I'm honestly curious, why do people all of sudden find a bunch of unclear photos of generic bargain bin bikes and ask for details about them?

Comment: I think @ojs was asking not about your questions (thanks for taking the time to improve this, by the way!) but about the general trend at the moment. We're getting a lot of people asking, "Here's a photo of a bike -- what is it?" and, honestly, it's not clear what the point is. Is it just curiosity or would it actually make a real difference to something if somebody said, "That's a Wonderbike Speedfold 6400"?

Comment: I do think we need to revisit our identify this bike policy. I've been tagging the identify postings so that we can see the type of pointless questions we get under this tag.

Comment: You can narrow it down a bit by knowing that there are only a handful of manufacturers of common folding bikes.  (Note that a popular place for a serial number is on the bottom of the bottom bracket housing.)

Comment: Unrelated to identification - it looks kinda fun to ride, in a sit-back and cruise way.  And knowing the brand name won't change how it rides in the slightest.  So if you like it, ride it.  If you don't like it, then pass the bike on to someone else who will enjoy it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I tell what year my bike was made?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/47078/how-can-i-tell-what-year-my-bike-was-made)

Comment: @TommyH so did you find any more information?  If so, do please add and accept your own answer.  That will help future searchers.

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer - you are looking at a frame design known as "crank forward" or "semi-recumbent"

The backreset is an integral part of the "seat" because the rider pushes against the backrest to power the pedal, and cannot raise themselves off the saddle and onto their pedals.  The rear suspension makes it a bit more comfortable given you can't unweight for bumps.

I'm going to hazard a guess that its an asian-source bike, and probably aimed at the elderly.

Comment: Note those folding pedals are incredibly bendy, and you cannot put more than ~50-100 watts through them without rising breakage.

Comment: "Aok1" branded brake lever appear to be a knock off for "AOKI" brand, which is a fairly budget brand in the first place.  That's not going to help with identification.  The writing on the cranks is useless too, sorry.