# I need help to identify my bmx bike by using serial numbers

Tags: identify-this-bike, bmx

20" bmx freestyle bicycle

[image]

Serial number is SNACEOSF18391

Comment: Are you sure SN is part of it?  could stand for "Serial Number" as in  "SN:ACEOSF18391"

Comment: Aside from the front gusset, the bike is indistinguishable from millions of others produced in numerous factories in China over the past 20 years.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I tell what year my bike was made?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/47078/how-can-i-tell-what-year-my-bike-was-made)

Comment: Reminds me of an old GT Mach 1 from the "tailbone" like protrusion behind the seat post from the frame. https://bmxmuseum.com/bikes/gt_bicycles/61109

Comment: Comment from an anonymous user:   "This serial number is new school mongoose [style/format]"

Answer (score 0):

That frame looks rather unusual - Could be worth searching google images for "BMX" till you find something that looks similar.  Also the detail of the front gusset looks very unsusual.  Not sure if its cosmetic or for strength at the headset.

I note the headset has a detangler for the rear brake line, and a Potts mod for the front brake line.  However there are no brake pads on the front calipers, so its not going to stop very well.

Saddle needs replacing or recovering, and you need air in that front tyre.

Based on handlebar angle, the previous rider was way too big for the bike.

I'm no BMX expert but based on the construction I'd guess 2000s for the age.

Sorry for no better info.

Comment: And odds are pretty good that the front brake cable is frozen up.