# Can anyone help me identify this touring bike?

Tags: identify-this-bike

I found [this LL Bean Touring Bike](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88qzA.jpg) on Facebook marketplace, the price looks pretty good and the owner said it was around 15 years old. I know that at some point, but not very recently, LL Bean Bikes were made by canondale. Can anyone give me any information on this bike?

[image]

Comment: Can you please add a clear clean close up photo of the brake calipers, and the derailleurs?  This is to see groupset/component brands and levels, and wear.

Comment: The smooth sanded welds are a Cannondale hallmark. Other stuff like threaded headset, dust caps on crank bolts, stem shifters and very narrow tires for a touring bike make this the bike look like it's from 80s, not early 2000s.

Comment: I highly doubt the bike is 15 years old. Maybe they had the bike for 15 years is what they meant?

Comment: Possible duplicate of a question that can help narrow down what year your bike was made and thus find an LL Bean catalogue or magazine article from that time:  [How can I tell what year my bike was made?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/47078/how-can-i-tell-what-year-my-bike-was-made)

Comment: Stem shifters suggests the bike is 20-30 years old.

Comment: Don't let our age estimate put you off.  Its a lovely looking bike and I would certainly ride it assuming it fits.

Comment: I'd move the shifters to down tube just to have something between my abdomen and pointy things. Modern brake levers and wider tires are huge improvement, unless you want to keep things period correct.

Answer (score 3):

I have a bike just like this one, same color - if you look on the back sprocket protector, (the black plastic piece), it will have Cannondale in raised letters. I bought the bike, along with a Cannondale LL Bean mountain bike in 1983 (I believe) from the catalog, and I'm pretty sure I still have the owners manual.  The rear rack is not original to the bike.  It has twelve speeds, which was pretty cool at the time when everyone else was still riding bikes with ten. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Cannondale did make bikes for LL Bean in the 1980s, and this looks like a Cannondale. I think @ojs has it.

Comment: Got any citations ?

Comment: I haven't been able to find the authoritative history of Cannondale's involvement with LL Bean, but a casual web search with those two names shows a lot of hits, and pictures of bikes identical to the OP's; oddly the [French Wikipedia entry on Cannondale](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cannondale_Bicycle_Corporation) mentions in, but not the English one.

Comment: Bingo. If I guess correctly, the re-branded model was ST500, which just happens to be the exact same color and have exact same details like non-tapered rear triangle tubes, the indent at middle of chainstays, dropout shape etc.

Answer (score 1):

It does sort of look like a Cannondale.  I think the tubes look a little small for aluminum but also look too big for steel.

It has the hallmark Cannondale plastic housing guides along the top tube.

You can check the crank and maybe the handlebars and see if they indicate 'Coda'.

Cannondale tourers came with rear racks that look like that.  I can't see the chainrings but most tourers come with a triple.  It does look like the rear is a long cage for a wider gear range.

But I would agree that this isn't 15 years old.  I wouldn't even put it in the 90s.  My T700 was a '94 and it had the cables below handlebar tape and had barcon shifters.  This looks more like an 80s bike with the combo stem shifters and non-aero brake cabling.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a fairly standard mid-late 90s road bike.   If owner is positive its only 15 years old then its potentially a BSO.

Nothing there makes it a tourer specifically.  The frame looks slightly chunky, but not thick like early aluminium bikes.  I could be wrong - do the magnet test to see if the frame and/or fork is steel.

The stem shifters say mid 90s, and the over-the-top brake cables would agree.

Someone's added a parcel rack, perhaps for commuting in a dry place?   Lack of mudguards/fenders suggest its not from a wet location.

The last person to ride it was not a strong rider, its in the lowest low hillclimbing gear.

Gumwall tyres are not common anymore - could they be original ?