# Help identifying a 1980s Shimano 600 road bike

Tags: identify-this-bike

[image]
Under the bottom bracket is a plastic piece with Raleigh on it. It has mavic ma40 wheels, cinelli handlebars, Shimano 600 2x6 gears, it weighs exactly 10kg (EDIT: without chain, derailleurs and front qr skewer), has shimano 600 brakes, a steel frame and has campagnolo top tube/friction shifters. I cannot see a serial number anywhere on the bike. Thank you for any help.
Harvey

Edit: I'm not just asking what year it is, I would also like to know brand and model if anyone knows since I cannot find a serial number.

Comment: It's a steel bike. There's no thing like a Shimano 600 bike. Shimano 600 was the name of the groupset that's now commonly named Ultegra and that dates from the late 1980s.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I tell what year my bike was made?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/47078/how-can-i-tell-what-year-my-bike-was-made)

Comment: Downtube shifters tell you it's from the 80s.  The brakes are premium quality for that era, so it's probably a pretty good bike (or was).  Can't tell much else.  Will be a little difficult finding derailers for it.

Comment: Daniel, I was going to go for Shimano 600 derailleurs which are surprisingly very cheap on eBay actually!

Comment: Its a gorgeous bike, and if the size and style suits you, then will be a good ride.  I'd try and keep it period, but when the cassette wears you may be forced to look at newer tech.   Those handlebars need to be angled up some more, it looks droopy now!

Comment: @Criggie thank you and yes I do need to angle the bars, I don't know why I didn't notice that haha!

Comment: My guess based on the lugs and frame style is a 1980-ish Raleigh Competition. A clearer image may help but it looks to be a silver one that was stripped and polished.

Comment: @NateWengert Yes! This does indeed seem to be the bike I have. Thank you very much. Not too bad for something I found in pieces in a bush by a road! (Don't worry it has been reported as found and no one reported it as missing or stolen)!

Comment: @HarveyBrackenbury Made an answer so it will show as being answered and avoid further close votes etc. Also a great bush find! cleaned up a bit should make a fine ride.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the style of lugs and overall frame style, My guess is a 1980 Raleigh Competition or Competition GS. It looks like one that has had the frame stripped and then polished.

Similar to this one seen here:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, will save some of the guess work in acquiring parts! Hopefully I won't be asking too many more questions about this and the repairs will go smoothly!

Comment: Ask away, there is a lot of good information on this site. Just be sure to search for questions before you ask them because there is a lot of good information to be found.