# Approx age of my Vindec

Tags: identify-this-bike

I have just bought an old Vindec Ventura, With 27x1 1/4 wheels 32x630 rims. It looks like a hybrid but wondering if it was a sports updated. Any one any gen at all on this model[image: I think description above asks the question.]Cheers all.

Comment: Reference this question too https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/47078/how-can-i-tell-what-year-my-bike-was-made

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I tell what year my bike was made?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/47078/how-can-i-tell-what-year-my-bike-was-made)

Comment: I had one bought for me in 1978.

Answer (score 3):

**Answer:: 80's road bike with modifications**

I'm guessing its an 80s road bike that has had the drops, quill stem, shifters and brake levers swapped out for a flat bar from a more modern MTB.

That's a gorgeous steel lugged frame

No bottle mounts are in the frame, which is why a PO has fitted a strap-on bottle cage.

Frame pump mounts also went out before the 90s, as did the uselessly-short mudguards.

That rear light looks like its powered by D batteries. so will be heavy.  I'd swap it for a pair of efficient LEDs, for safety when riding at night, unless you're trying for a period bike.

The cranks are cotterless, so its no older than the 80s or that was also changed - there's a triple chainring, which may have been fitted with the MTB bars or may be original.

There may be more info in the rear cluster/cassette and the rear derailleur, and the brand/model of brake calipers.

---

If it runs okay then air up the tyres and ride it.  I'd suggest changing all four brake pads, and examine the tyres for deterioration.

If the tyres are getting iffy, consider replacing the whole wheel with a more common 700c aluminium rim.  Those 27" wheels look like chromed steel and wet weather braking is wishful thinking!  Downside of this is the brake calipers may no longer reach a slightly smaller wheel and may not have as much pressure under braking.

Comment: The derailleur is Shimano The crank cogs and shafts are Powerwheel. the brake calipers are Weinman type 730. does that help clarify further

Comment: Fitting 700 front with Sturmey Archer hub dynamo will match up to right lamps. with removable LED's. Replace handlebar stem fit Raleigh sports upright bars. Fit old silver plastic mudguards. Period look retaining more modern gearing with its extra cog. It will be well ridden. Deraileur is marked SIS does that seem a retro fit?

Comment: I guess the point of the mudguards is to keep road crud out of the brake calipers, rather than to keep it off the rider.

Answer (score 2):

I had a new vindecventura when I was a kid, it had drop handlebars and was red like yours. It was a seventies bike, mine was around 1978.

Comment: Cool that’s good to know about the year, and confirming that it had drop handlebars originally. Welcome to the site, don’t forget to check out the [tour]

Answer (score -1):

I got one of these for Christmas in 1967/8. Happy memories seeing this.

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles!  It seems that this bike was produced over a number of years; is there anything specific about yours that matches this one?  (That might be different from one made in 70s-80s like other answers have suggested.)