# Looking for information about older bikes

Tags: vintage, bike-selection

Does anyone know of any good web sites to do research on older bikes? Been fixing bikes for a few years but just recently got into vintage bikes. I want to find out all i can right down to frame makers.

Comment: Related: [How can I tell what year my bike was made?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/47078/7309. Unfortunately *" Questions seeking product/service/learning material recommendations or item valuations are off-topic"*

Comment: This is just too broad to answer -- there's no end to the potential for adding more and more links to more and more sites. That's not what the Stack Exchange format is about. We want to be the answer, not a place people go to find links to the answer.

Comment: google.com is a good starting point.  Without more details in the question, the answer ends up being just as vague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several forums that cater to vintage bikes, one of the best in my humble opinion is the Cabe - The Classic and Antique Bicycle Exchange

- [www.thecabe.com](https://thecabe.com/forum/)

There is an exponential amount of knowledge on there and the people really know their stuff.

Another is Classic Vintage Cycles

- [www.classicvintagecycles.org/](http://www.classicvintagecycles.org/)

Lastly bikeforums.com has vintage section as well

- https://www.bikeforums.net/classic-vintage/

These are the 3 i am most familiar with, however I'm sure there are many more. There are a couple dedicated websites as well but most are bicycle specific such as vintage BMX, or only Muscle bikes, or Schwinn's.

As much as i hate to say it google with be your best friend for this but the CABE is a good forum to start on, it will likely lead you to other resources as well. Hope this helps.