# Identify year of specialized s-works tarmac?

Tags: road-bike, identify-this-bike, specialized-bikes

Can anyone identify this specialized s-works tarmac? The seller says it's a 2013, but I haven't found it.

[image]

Comment: Best ask the seller for a look at the sales docket, or warranty paperwork.    In actuality - the exact "year" of a bike matters less than its condition and wear and crash-history.  Note that valuations are off topic for this site.   Good luck with your ride.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I tell what year my bike was made?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/47078/how-can-i-tell-what-year-my-bike-was-made)

Comment: Ask the seller for the serial number.  If seller dodges the question, run away very quickly.    If they quote a number, telephone specialized's customer support and ask if its a real number.

Comment: The thing looks sloppy enough that I'm thinking Chinese knockoff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking on bikepedia.com, I can only find listings from 2012 and 2013 for Specialized Tarmac SL4 Pro, or S-Works Tarmac SL4. The frame in the photo seems to have decals for both 'S Works' AND 'Pro' (on the seat tube). This seems inconsistent with any photographs I can see on google images. SWorks frames tend to have 'SL4' on the seat tube instead but I have only seen photos taken from the drive side.

Also, the colour of the red decals on the bike seem a suspiciously similar shade to those on the wheels, which makes me skeptical even further. I haven't seen any google images results in this paint scheme, and expect that you haven't either, hence the question here.

I would ask the seller for more information, for warranty documentation, proof of purchase, a frame number that you can check with Specialized etc. Maybe it's all legit and original, or maybe it's been resprayed. If so, the owner shouldn't have any issue with answering your questions. But if it seems too good to be true, be prepared to walk away.

Comment: So reading between the lines, you're querying the legitimacy of the bike, that it may be a knock off ?  Excellent thought.   There is no Specialized serial database online, but OP can email or telephone Specalized and quote the serial number for verification.

Answer (score 3):

This was too long to comment so here is my input.

I would be wary that it is not a knock-off, it looks off to me, I don't think that there were ever any factory produced Specialized tarmacs that looked quite like that. Hawk racing is a wheel builder but if they are legit those would be custom hand built carbon wheels worth 1800$.. but the font is not their usual font and is the same as that on the frame.

Hawk's website can be found [here](https://www.hawk-racing.com/product/veyron-v45-clincher/)

So it's either a highly custom legit very expensive bike, or a knock off potentially chinese frame and wheel set with matching decals. I would do as others have advised and call Specialized with a serial number. If he is legit he should have no problem with that.