# Schwinn Circuit Identification

Tags: identify-this-bike, schwinn

I have a Schwinn Circuit that I got years ago from my father. I'm almost positive it is a 1987 or 1988 model based on when I remember him buying it.

It is red, with white leather seat and handle bars. It has a Sante gearing I believe and Cinelli handlebar. The frame is Columbus.

I don't have pictures right now, but hopefully this is sufficient to identify it. If so, what year is it? If not, what more information would be needed.

Comment: Get the serial number and feed it into https://bikehistory.org/serial-number.html  This only works for Schwinn.

Comment: @Criggie I plug in the serial number, but it is incorrectly stating it was built 5/1/1958. :P

Comment: hmm sorry - that site stops in 1982.  "This tool works for Schwinn bikes from 1948 to 1982."    so your 1987~8 is too new.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I tell what year my bike was made?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/47078/how-can-i-tell-what-year-my-bike-was-made)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it look like this?
[image]

That's a top of the line model for the time, weighing in at 9 kilos, for a steel bike.

Here's the year's specs for 1988
[image: Specs]

[And here's a story with more info](https://mauisvintage.blogspot.com/2010/03/finally-1988-schwinn-circuit-complete.html)

Comment: @Criggie - image only answers are dispreferred. Can you provide some more text? :)

Comment: @RoboKaren fair call - will do so this evening.

Answer (score 1):

It's an 88 if it originally had a white seat and handlebar tape and it's an 89 if it had a black seat and handlebar tape.  So yours is an 88.

Comment: Very helpful, do you have a source you could [edit] in to your answer? It would be good for readers to reference, and possibly to read more