# Please help me identify this bicycle (Peugot)

Tags: identify-this-bike, touring-bikes, peugeot

I recently finished a renovation project on a classic Peugeot road/touring bike and was wondering what the model and production year of this bicycle is.

I tried but could not find anything myself. Perhaps one of you more knowledgable in classic bikes could help me identify the model/production year. I've attached a number of photos.

Some additonal info:

- Simplex derailleurs
- Frame number: y71210232
- Atom hubs
- Rigida rims

[image: peugeot]

Here is a link to the rest of the images:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1vWegk_w2W92iAWccGJoYzEkW7v3aPSQz?usp=sharing

Thank you very much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I tell what year my bike was made?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/47078/how-can-i-tell-what-year-my-bike-was-made)

Comment: I'd guess an 80s touring bike, because of the downtube shifter, the front rack, the brakes, and the steel spoke protector.

Comment: Mafac brakes, plastic capped shift levers, front ring protector, thin seatpost set in a bushing and cottered steel crank. I'd say late 60's early 70's. I've had a similar one in those days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks a lot like [this 1976 UE-8](https://farm5.static.flickr.com/4045/4704398485_77cccc75b3_b.jpg), except for the front rack.

Comment: Thank you so much it does indeed look like the UE-8. Have a great day!