# Do we know this type/brand/model of vintage bicycle?

Tags: vintage

[image][image]JUNIOR (MADE IN AUSTRIA) AND THE FRAME SAYS ''JUNIOR FLIPPER''

[image]

Comment: Made in ??? -- What does it say?

Comment: Made in Austria

Comment: JUNIOR (MADE IN AUSTRIA)
AND THE FRAME SAYS ''JUNIOR FLIPPER''

Comment: Well then that's what it is!

Comment: Looks like a 70s road bike. The cottered cranks date it to that decade.

Comment: Thanks eveerybody. I cant find a brand such as JUNIOR. I want to know how old is it.

Comment: Add clear, well lit photos of the rear derailleur and shifters. Someone may be able to identify and date those - which will give you the approximate age of the bike

Comment: If you want to find the age, this question should help: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/47078/11160

Answer (score -3):

ITs a generic BSO made for the 70/80's 10sp market, likely basic cro mo or gas pipe type.heavy as lead...not worth wasting effort or money on..

Comment: Anything's worth spending some time and effort on if you want to and enjoy that sort of thing.  Just because its a product of its time doesn't make it a worthless bike.  OP is looking for info on the model or brand, but other than an approximate age we've come up a blank on this one.

Comment: 2x5 speed, cottered steel cranks, plastic gear levers, high flange hubs (Maillard - helicomatic?) means late 60s. Reminds me the style of a Peugeot from those days. Cleaned and rebuilt might be a thing for white road ride events.

Comment: http://graz.radln.net/cms/beitrag/11375074/105566718/?fbclid=IwAR1FcdI0NHUwbyu02APHoAWnV2PGZFYhFvD_5a_iADIPelzN-Jz9n7C-0_c

Comment: @PavlosIordanopoulos that looks more like a separate answer rather than a comment on this answer.  Please post it as an answer, and include a summary of the relevant information (ie not just a link-only answer.)  Good spotting!