# Please help me identify this bike frame?

Tags: frames, identify-this-bike

Please help me identify this bike frame for I am a newbie/novice. I will greatly apppreciate it. It appears similar to some 1950s Huffmans, but I am far from certain.

Thanks to all in advance who help!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Look in the "Related" column on the right side of this page.  This question is asked regularly, and it's usually difficult to say, beyond "old" or "Chinese" or some such.  Yours is fairly distinctive and fairly old, so you may get lucky, but probably not.

Comment: Note that if there is any bit of the head badge remaining, you should probably give us a picture of that.

Comment: Unfortunately, the head badge is missing. Thank you for your response and your suggestion.

Comment: Looks very similar to Huffy Radio Bike, but those usually have radio between top tubes, and seat cluster does not match either.

Comment: @Klaster_1 - The layout of the top tubes is fairly standard for that era.

Comment: @ODRules - It would be a little helpful to know what size bike this is.  When you line the bike up next to a 24 inch or 26 inch bike (or maybe a smaller kid's bike), which does it seem to match the best, in terms of wheel clearance?

Comment: I am at work now but when I get a chance I will do that. I thought the frame was smaller than a 26 inch bike but I will make sure. I might not get an opportunity until late tonight or until the morning. It sounds like that I might I have the era (1950s) and manufacturer right (Huffman/Huffy)?

Comment: The answers in the following should help you pin down the rough decade of the bike: [How can I tell what year my bike was made?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/47078/how-can-i-tell-what-year-my-bike-was-made)

Comment: @RoboKaren I'm not sure any of those answers is really applicable to a naked frame (except the possibility of the serial number being enough to identify the manufacturer _and_ encoding the year, which is a real long-shot).

Comment: @DavidRicherby I disagree. Presence of lawyers lips, bottom bracket style, brake mounts, rear hub spacing, presence of shifter lugs, Steele tube, all help narrow down to a decade.

Comment: @RoboKaren But none of those answers have been written yet.

Comment: Hahaha. Good point.

Comment: @RoboKaren - There don't appear to be lawyer lips, shifter lugs, brake bosses.  The rear hub spacing seems wide, but hard to say without measurements or at least info on the wheel diameter.  The BB housing seems large for a 3-piece, small for a 1-piece.  (But again hard to say without knowing the wheel size.)  Not really much you can say, other than it's pretty old.