# What year is Dyno "air" anodized red 3mag wheel

Tags: identify-this-bike, bmx

What year is my Dyno "air" anodized red 3mag wheel?

[image]

Comment: For what's it worth, and from what I can remember being posted around various places, the first four numbers of your serial are year / month so 9601 would be 1996 / Jan if it's definitely a Dyno Air. Various model like the nitros used a different format.

Comment: Unless there were _very_ distinctive changes from year to year, it's very unlikely that anyone will be able to identify the precise year from a photo. Also, it's unlikely that knowing the year will make any practical difference to your life.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why shouldn't I care what model/make/year my bicycle is?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52060/why-shouldnt-i-care-what-model-make-year-my-bicycle-is)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I tell what year my bike was made?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/47078/how-can-i-tell-what-year-my-bike-was-made)

Answer (score 1):

This is a 1999 Dyno Air from [bmxmuseum.com](https://bmxmuseum.com/bikes/dyno/45822)
[image]
The problem with this picture is the bent seat post.

Researching on bmxmuseum.com Dyno does not start using a [straight seat post until 2001](https://bmxmuseum.com/bikes/dyno/41953)
[image]
The problem with this picture is the rear wheel drop out is very different than the 1998. The rear drop out from 1999 is a match for your bike (as near as I can tell from the fuzzy picture in the original post).

In 1998 Dyno located the rear brake on the seat stays, not on the chain stays behind the crank. The brake was moved in 1999.

So, the frame is a 1999 Dyno with a swapped out straight seat post