# I need to know what model and year my Rocky mountain bike is

Tags: mountain-bike

RM01XXG02FT0151 this is the serial number

Comment: Please have a look at https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/47078/how-can-i-tell-what-year-my-bike-was-made

Comment: https://www.bikes.com/en/our-story shows the brand "Rocky Mountain" started in 1981 and is still active in 2019.  If you mean a mountain bike branded "Rocky" then that's something else.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by some of the other Rocky Mountain bikes serial formats that I've seen on other forums, its probably a 2001 model. RM = Rock Mountain, 01 = 2001.