# Looking for year for this bike

Tags: road-bike, identify-this-bike

[image: Raliegh]

I just bought this bike a Raleigh Professional 10 speed, I am trying to ID year. Serial number is hard to read, maybe 00Y00672.

I am excited about this bike 10 Speed. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please have a look at https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/47078/how-can-i-tell-what-year-my-bike-was-made

Answer (score 6):

First, for most purposes, it doesn’t [really matter](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52060/why-shouldnt-i-care-what-model-make-year-my-bicycle-is) what year your bike was made.

Second, I was curious and I Googled. There’s little information about this particular model, and I can’t find an exact match.

That said, my guess is that the frameset is from the early 2000s, probably pre-2004. Raleigh USA’s 2004 [catalog](https://community.raleighusa.com/sites/default/files/inline-files/04-raleigh-catalog.pdf) shows a Professional model with an aluminum frame and carbon seat stays. By my recollection, aluminum with carbon stays had a brief moment of popularity around that time. Your frame does look like an aluminum frame, but it doesn’t look like it has carbon seat stays. So, let’s guess pre-2004. (Note: see answer by @DeleterUser - this bike is likely a 2002 Professional, which should have a steel frame.)

The components look like Campagnolo Centaur or Chorus. In the early 2000s, those were all polished silver components. That corroborates that this was an early 2000s frame. I doubt those components came stock, however. Nearly all OEM specifications were Shimano components. (Note: see answer by @DeleterUser - the 2002 Professional came stock with a Chorus/Centaur mix.)

I’m less familiar with Mavic wheels, but those look like the first or second generation of Ksyrium SSC wheels. Looking at Mavic's history page, they appear to have introduced the Ksyrium in 1999. In 2002, they filed a patent for milling the rim in between the spokes. That should be the second generation Ksyrium. It looks like your rim has some silver in between the spokes, which means it should be that milled version. If your wheels are anodized black between the spokes, then that's a first generation Ksyrium. Of course, the wheelset could have been bought at a different time from the frameset, and they probably sold the first generation Ksyriums alongside the second generation ones for a few years. (Note: see answer by @DeleterUser - this probably isn't the stock wheelset, although if my identification is correct, the wheelset is definitely from a similar era.)

Side note: you need to close that front brake. There’s a small sliding button on the levers near where the brake lever pivots. Push it in.

Comment: Yep, I would say early 2000s.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like a 2002.

https://www.bikepedia.com/QuickBike/BikeSpecs.aspx?year=2002&brand=Raleigh%20&model=Professional

Raleigh only has the Professional listed for 2002 and 2003.  The 2003 has a different color scheme.

Comment: Kudos for giving correct information! Looks like my estimation of the timeframe was correct. However, I was wrong about a) the frame material and b) the OEM component spec. It does appear that the seller changed the wheelset.

Comment: The seller or someone previous for sure (as well as a new tapejob).  17 years is time enough for a couple of owner changes.

Comment: Thank you for the information...  I am the second owner ... He stated early 2000's but was not sure of the year ... The rims were changed out  and I received the original rims also.  I am extremely happy with my purchase ... Not sure of value but it doesn't matter  I am Happy ... Thanks again... Button pushed in also. Thanks still learning