# I have a gravity bike how do I find out the model

Tags: identify-this-bike

How do I find yyear and model on a gravity bike

Comment: Clarify:  Do you have a "Gravity" brand bike, or a bike designed for steep descents?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why shouldn't I care what model/make/year my bicycle is?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52060/why-shouldnt-i-care-what-model-make-year-my-bicycle-is)

Comment: Possibly useful: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/47078/how-can-i-tell-what-year-my-bike-was-made and https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1337/how-do-i-ask-a-good-id-my-bike-question

Answer (score 3):

Look if you can find anything indicating the brand and name of the model. Then do an image search on the net and see if a bike looks like yours. You may also try to find old catalogues or find the bike on an archived copy of the sites of vendor, brand, or manufacturer.

You may also find our most recommended question and its answers helpful: [Why shouldn't I care what model/make/year my bicycle is?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/52060/30402)