# Which year was my stump jumper made?

Tags: mountain-bike

It is a 1986 or 1987 stump jumper sport, serial number DS636887. I have the original saddle and all equipment as when purchased. Only the tires are not original.

[image: stumpjumper sport]

Comment: Welcome, we do not do any valuations at this site.

Comment: And there's no universal database of bike serial numbers, unlike for cars. Specialized is more likely to be able to help you than we are.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I tell what year my bike was made?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/47078/how-can-i-tell-what-year-my-bike-was-made)

Comment: There's nothing about the bike that strongly suggests a particular vintage.  The lugged frame, canti brakes, 3x crank are all consistent with the late 80s or early 90s.  Only Specialized could (possibly) associate the serial number with a year of manufacture.

Comment: BTW - that's a loverly bike, and you'll enjoy riding it.

Comment: It is a lovely bike, but unfortunately, it has almost no value as a collectible item. This is why Vladimir commented that we don’t do valuations. Even if we did, knowing which year this is wouldn’t change the value very much.

Comment: One note aside: while looking at the picture, I've noticed that the safety hook in the fork under the bridge cable of the brake has been replaced by a simple bolt. The hook is meant to catch the bridge cable if the main brake cable snaps and prevent it from getting caught by the tyre. Possible explanation: The bike may have had mudguards at some time or a reflector on a bracket.

Comment: thanks for comment about the safety hook, but the bike is exactly how I bought it. I still have original seat. I added the back rack and water bottle holders. bought at bike store in atlanta in 86 or 87 I believe. i went to bike shop recently, to have tires and gears checked. The technician said it was a collectible bike??