# How do I determine kuota kharma bike year?

Tags: road-bike, identify-this-bike

Black carbon frame with some white and pale pink details.
Name is kuota kharma

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site! With that few details and no pictures at all, it is impossible to help you. Please provide more details, especially as many well lit pictures of the bike's details. Also, please elaborate: what difference knowing a year of manufacturing will make to you? Is it that important to know it? See this Q: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52060

Comment: I'll echo what Grigory says, and add this:  I've had some success with Google Image Search.  With a sufficiently detailed search term, I can often find a picture which leads to a website which leads to a model year.  But that first step is essential-- check the picture carefully.  Does it match up in great detail?  Naturally, replaceable bits (tires, etc) may not match, but frame trim and colors and so on should.  This may help.  It may not.  I'd suggest considering whether there's another way to accomplish whatever you'd be using the year for, though.

Comment: This really would have been easier with more details, like a photo.

Comment: Adding to Andrew's comment: Google will sometimes pull up results from Bicycle Blue Book, which may have stock photos of the bike. You sometimes see older reviews on cycling media sites. Sometimes, these can help place an approximate date. For reference, Kuota is the manufacturer (based in Italy, frames likely made in the Far East because almost everyone does that), and the Kharma is the model. Late 2000s or early 2010s is my guess, for whatever that's worth. It appears not to be a current model.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I tell what year my bike was made?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/47078/how-can-i-tell-what-year-my-bike-was-made)

Answer (score 1):

A quick google returns results that range from 2008-2010, 2012 and 2014.

Also mentioned is an Ironman World Champ in 2004, and that the AG2R La Mondiale pro tour team rode the brand from 2010 to 2013.

If you use the Image search at https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=kuota+kharma then there's a bunch of photos, so its a matter of picking out your bike.  Based on "pink"  guess its this one:

[image]

<sup>From https://sg.carousell.com/p/kuota-kharma-evo-full-carbon-road-bike-88677778/</sup>

This is a 2013 year model, reviewed positiviely at
https://www.bikeradar.com/reviews/bikes/road-bikes/kuota-kharma-evo-review/