# I'm trying to figure out what make this bike is

Tags: identify-this-bike

This bicycle was given to me and I'm not sure was the make of it I've tried look in the serial number up on Google but I came up with nothing so hopefully you can help me with trying to figure out what kind of bike this is the Serial number is SNHFD10K02145

Comment: related: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/32872/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-serial-number, https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/47078/how-can-i-tell-what-year-my-bike-was-made. Your best bet is to ask the person who gave it to you, though.

Comment: Serial numbers are generally useless.  We need, at a minimum, a few pictures.

Comment: Photos, please.  Right now we can't even tell you what colour it is, or if it has wheels.

Comment: As for serial numbers - https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/32872/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-serial-number

Answer (score 2):

Is this the bike you have, perhaps?

[image]

Comment: I thought it was liquorice at first glance.   Is it wrought iron ?

Comment: @Criggie - I've no idea.

Comment: Possibly a Gianluca Gimini creation. https://www.bicycling.com/news/a20028107/designer-brings-sketched-bikes-to-life-and-the-results-are-wonderful/

Comment: Actually Thomas Kuodis - https://newirishart.com/irish-artists/tomas-kuodis-artist

Comment: @Criggie: My guess was pasta.

Comment: @Carel good observation -  "more pasta more fasta"   could be a timetrial frame.