# How do i determine Bianchi Infinito year of manufacture from these labels WBK446115F and TPJ611528F?

Tags: serial-number

How do i determine Bianchi Infinito year of manufacture from these labels WBK446115F  and TPJ611528F?
These labels are on the frame bottom bracket.

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles!  You might want to check out https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/47078/43557 which has some ideas that could help.

Answer (score 1):

Phone the bianchi distributor and ask them. The UK one is very helpful.

web search Bianchi Distributor (country x)

I'll add that it's normally quite easy to tell the model year by the livery. With Bianchi you can also tell the original specification by the livery. Compare yours to the back catalogue.

Comment: Thank you, Joe.  I've followed through by speaking with then sending photos to a  BianchiUSA representative who indicated they would assist.  I'll report back what I learn. Take care. Luke