# Gary fisher Marlin serial # WTU087C2290C

Tags: mountain-bike, identify-this-bike, valves

What’s the age of the bike?

Can I use either a schraeder valve or presta valve tube for the wheels?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I tell what year my bike was made?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/47078/how-can-i-tell-what-year-my-bike-was-made)

Answer (score 4):

If you contact Trek Bicycles, they may be able to give you info on the age of your bike based on the serial number, since they acquired the brand. If you want an estimate of the age from the cycling community, it would help to post pictures of the bicycle -- the entire bicycle and a close-up of the drivetrain (chain, sprockets, derailleurs), both from the right side of the bicycle.

As for your specific question, the valve you can use is going to depend on the size of the hole in the rims. The Schraeder valve hole is larger than the Presta, but I don't know the exact dimensions. Schraeder was commonly used on mountain bikes back when I owned them (1989-1999). If you have rims drilled for Schraeder, you can find a rubber insert for the rim that will reduce the size of the hole. I don't know that it's strictly necessary, but reducing the size of the hole will support the inner tube material so the tube doesn't herniate, and I'd be reluctant to use a Presta valve in a Schraeder hole for longer than it takes to get home from a ride.

Enjoy your Fisher. I had one that was stolen 30 years ago, and I still miss it.

Answer (score 2):

Funnily enough, bikeindex.org comes up with a very similar S/N, belonging to a Trek bicycle from 2019.

https://bikeindex.org/bikes/409317

Trek and Gary Fisher brands are part of the same bike conglomerate, so it is likely that both frames are coming from the same factory.

I guess then that your bicycle is from 2019 or 2018. Regarding valves: it depends on the currently installed rims, which may or may not be the same as the one originally provided by the manufacturer (sometimes bikeshops swap them, because of whaterver reason from pleasing another customers, to shipping damage, etcetc...)