# Hi, what year were this two bikes made? serial number on seat clamp on frame is H180003 second one is M068662. thank you!

Tags: road-bike, frames, identify-this-bike, vintage

i need year they were made please!

Comment: Bicycle serial numbers do not contain the information you are looking for.

Comment: Why do you need an exact year?  a bike is not like a car where every "year" model might have different parts.  Tell us what you're trying to achieve please ?

Comment: @Criggie actually, aren't a lot of cars also the same or very similar from year to year until there's a generation change? I think a product cycle may be 3-4 years for modern cars (that was the case with the Honda Fit and Toyota Prius, I believe, and I own/have owned both of these). Anyway, the product cycles for older bikes are longer than that, and the components will generally mount to standard interfaces anyway

Comment: @WeiwenNg true - but 90% of the bikes out there would use shimano or sram.  The year is way less important, hence why asking about the underlying need/question/issue and avoiding a X/Y problem.

Comment: The first one is from 1803 and the second one is much earlier, probably week 68 of 1662. I'm surprised they've survived

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I tell what year my bike was made?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/47078/how-can-i-tell-what-year-my-bike-was-made)

Answer (score 3):

Based on the information provided, the range is somewhere between 1880 and 2021.

If you post a clear and well-lit photo of the bikes we can probably estimate within a decade.

You may be interested to read some existing Q&A

- [Why shouldn't I care what model/make/year my bicycle is?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52060/why-shouldnt-i-care-what-model-make-year-my-bicycle-is)
- [What is the purpose of a serial number?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/32872/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-serial-number)
- [How can I tell what year my bike was made?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/47078/how-can-i-tell-what-year-my-bike-was-made/)