# Help in Dating a bike

Tags: brakes, identify-this-bike

Just read your very helpful article on [dating a bike](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/47078/how-can-i-tell-what-year-my-bike-was-made)

You covered approx. dates for shifters, cassettes and cotterpins. My question is : could the style of brakes (even the brand) help in the approx. dating process ?

Comment: Well, bikes tend to be at least as old as their oldest components, so yes, of course. It would help to know, what kind of brakes? Any markings on them? Do you have pictures?

Comment: Cotterpins?  On the cranks?  Boom 1970s at the newest, with a tiny chance its a later reproduction.  Cranks are unlikely to be changed out, unless its a race bike of some sort.

Comment: It's nice to buy it some chain lube and new handle bar tape. They tend to like that. Be sure to wipe it down after each use, they like to look their best. Oh... not that kind of dating?

Answer (score 2):

Yes of course. Brakes have changed in technology over the years, and manufacturers have come and gone.

If you identify the style of brake (side pull, centre pull, double pivot, caliper brake, V brake, disc brake etc. etc.) that will give you an indication of the era the bike is from. If you can identify the maker and model, by reading the letters on the brake,  you can research when that model was on sale.

HTH