# I bought a Diamondback bmx at a yardsale but the decals are gone. The serial # is ACY4J14097. What year and model is this? Its an all chrome frame

Tags: frames, bmx

Diamondback bmx serial # ACY4J14097. All chrome frame. DB stamped into back frame gussets. What year and model is this? All decals have been removed.

Comment: For BMX bikes in particular, the manufacturer is very often a random factory in China, and it's both difficult to establish who manufactured the bike, and pointless to try.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the site.  We see a lot of these "What is my BMX?" questions, and they are all of this format, with missing decals or paint and no more than a serial number.  It may not even be a diamondback - sellers can lie.

You may be interested to read some existing Q&A on this topic

- [Why shouldn't I care what model/make/year my bicycle is?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52060/why-shouldnt-i-care-what-model-make-year-my-bicycle-is)
- [What is the purpose of a serial number?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/32872/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-serial-number/)
- [How can I tell what year my bike was made?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/47078/how-can-i-tell-what-year-my-bike-was-made)

The bike you have is what it is.  As long as its undamaged then you can clean, tune, and ride it, or let the kids ride it and have fun.

Most BMXs are physically similar, with technological changes over time being limited to materials and gearing and different quality of parts.   So "age" is not particularly important, and overall condition is.

Yours is chromed, which is a very hard-wearing finish that is difficult to remove and poor at holding paint.  When it gets scratched they can be hard to repair.

Ultimately, a bike has the purpose of being ridden and enjoyed.  Without that, it is just scrap metal.

[image] A diamondback headtube badge from the 2000's

You can choose to make it functionally rideable and mechanically safe by making sure the brakes work etc, or you might prefer it to be a perfected shiny glossy show-pony that never gets ridden.  Or pass it on to the next person to enjoy.

One might choose to paint it in Celeste and apply Bianchi decals, just to wind up the brand fanboys.  Or get some custom decals cut that say "TIMBIKE" or whatever.

Almost every BMX out there is functionally identical so the chance of a "rare" frame is almost 0.  IMO the worst thing you can do is store it "in case it becomes valuable" which is vanishingly unlikely.

Fix/ride and enjoy it, or pass it on.