# Finding the age of my bike

Tags: mountain-bike

I'm trying to find out my age of my Rocky Mountain Hammer bike. The serial number is RMB05050404 but I can't find anywhere to input the number in order to further my search.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I tell what year my bike was made?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/47078/how-can-i-tell-what-year-my-bike-was-made)

Comment: A photo would be more helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Compare your bike to https://gearselected.com/rocky-mountain-hammer-review-10-years-on/  which documents a 2002 build.

Also, look over your frame for **"Made in Canada"** to help date it - in 1999 they stopped making bikes in Canada according to: 
https://www.theglobeandmail.com/report-on-business/small-business/sb-marketing/bike-maker-refuses-to-pedal-down-market/article4258882/

Additionally I see the company has a decent archive at https://resources.bikes.com/en/bike-archive  so start looking for your bike.
You may be able to narrow it down by looking at your bike for words on the frame to denote a model.

Your last-last resort is to contact the company directly at https://intl.bikes.com/pages/contact 
or even register the bike to yourself at https://intl.bikes.com/pages/bike-registration