How to find info on a 2nd hand bicycle with only a stamped number under the crank housing?
I have not a clue what or who's bicycle this is. It's been polished out with only a serial number remaining for identification. The guy where I bought it said it might be an older Genesis (2011, wow that's old - really lol) .... There's a couple bikes that kinda look like it but I don't know , kinda new to bicycles ....Anyways that all I think I know. Any ideas ? I have photos available.

A good start would be to post those photos? But https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52060/why-shouldnt-i-care-what-model-make-year-my-bicycle-is

I'm going to guess its a BMX.  Could you add the photos with [edit] please ?

@Criggie, see this question, as it says in the header, as an 'how to find out,' not as an 'identify this bike' question. Adding photos now would invalidate my answer. Asking a new question with photos is the way to go.

A little more helpful version of the suggested post: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/47078/how-can-i-tell-what-year-my-bike-was-made

I'm new to this site and do not know how to add photos as requested. Please advise.

Wow, that's a lot of parts that don't really belong together. There's no way the bike left factory like this. The handlebar contraption looks scary.

This answer is based on the original question, how to find information on what bike OP has, not on the later edit with photos which turned it into a "what bike is this" question.
Original answer:
The best place I know to identify a bike is here.
Make a new question and in it post photos, an overview of the drive side and details of all that can help like the front, handle bar, drive train, rear rack if there and so on.
If any brand marks remain also those. Serial number, while not enough in itself, can help people to distinguish between different brands as some have certain ways to make the numbers.
Add text with all information you have on the bike, what has been said about it. Do include your own conclusions on brand, age and so on.
Without good photos we cannot begin to find a bike. If you can not yet post photos here host them somewhere else on internet and post url's of the photos as links here.

You have... a lot going on there.
Estimating based on the size of your wall power sockets, this is a 26" wheel bike.   It appears to be built on some kind of MTB frame, which started life as either a hard-tail or a fully rigid bike.
The fork looks to have been changed, because the chrome is a different sheen to the rest of the bike, and appears to be thinner tube - it looks almost  "dainty" compared to the thicker tubes on the rest of the frame.I guess this was done to get a disk brake mount - the main frame does not have a disk brake mount.
The wheels are somewhat aero in profile, which would be unlikely on a MTB as stock so these have been swapped too.   The tyres look quite large, so make sure they're not too-wide for the inner width.   Curiously, the metal spoke protector has a very `80s look to it.
Gearing looks fairly standard for a 2000's MTB, with a triple chainring crank and a fairly narrow range ~7 speed cassette.   The front derailleur cable appears to have come detached from its mount and is hanging loose.
There is no rear brake, and as such has a limited safety factor.   I see posts for rear V brakes, but someone has attached two red reflectors pointing sideways, which is odd.   The rear wheel has a brake track, I'd strongly recommend fitting some V brakes and make them work.
The rear rack is completely cantilevered off the seat post, and has no stays supporting the rear end.  Those are good for a small lunchbox or maybe a light jacket, but no significant loads.  If you want a rear parcel rack/carrier, look for one with stays that go down to the rear dropouts.   The only positive of this rack is that it will kind-of work as a mudguard/fender, but there are much better and lighter options.  The rack also looks very close to rubbing on the rear tyre.
Steering - whoa nelly I see a very long steerer tube from the fork, that passes through the head tube.  Instead of cutting it to length, the builder has used a spare stem to secure the bearings. Then there's a quill stem that has been secured into the unsupported steerer tube.   I don't know what the grey plastic bit is, possibly a seal to exclude rainwater?And on top we see a medium-rise BMX-style Y bar.
I would guess the previous owner either had back pain, or a lack of flexibility.  This has lead them to choose a "sit up" position on a frame that was more "lean-forward"To reach this goal, they've used an unhealthy amount of stackup.
The Dangers here are excess leverage, and that a steerer tube for threadless is not designed to contain an expanding wedge in a quill stem.   Additionally this setup will have terrible handling.

My guess is the builder was going for an "all metal" look and used whatever components contributed to that.
TODO LIST:

Add a rear brake that works
Fix that loose inner cable
Lower the handlebar to something safer and remove the quill stem.
Remove the sideways reflectors on the brake pads, and swap all the wheel reflectors for legal ones in your location.  Colour rules vary around the world.
Get another cyclist to give the bike a safety check - there's a good chance we haven't seen everything.


As for answering your specific question on identifying this bike - What's the point?   The bike has been changed around so much that I bet only the frame and cranks and maybe the seatpost is original.
Knowing it started life as a "XYZ" brand isn't going to tell you anything.
Frankly, given the amount of change you'd be well placed to signwrite "TamiBike" on the downtube instead.
It's certainly a unique bike !
